# How to access variables from other objects in C#?

Tags: c#, variables, methods

As you can see, I have a number of variables setup. However, I wish to multiply the 'lengthInchConverted' and 'widthInchConverted' and output them to a textbox called 'totalAreaCM'.

I have set the methods as public, however, I cannot access the variable from the top method. How should I go about fixing this?

[image: img]

In the second screenshot I commented out the line of code to better illustrate my point. The 'Calculate' button will be for something else in the future.

[image: img]

Comment: Please copy and paste your code into the question rather than providing screen shots.

Comment: Keep length/width in cm as class members.

Comment: Store the variables outside for the methods. You cannot access the body of a method, especially if you knew how those work. Those type of variables live on the stack, which means they're not even existing in memory when the function isn't executed.

Answer (score 0):

The methods may be public, but the variables are not. The variable 'lengthInchConverted' and 'widthInchConverted' are only accessible by the function they're declared in. You could declare them at the class level to make them accessible by each function in the class.